# Can mingw be used to compile code for Windows Vista or 7?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, windows-vista, mingw

I noticed that the included headers for Windows development (such as `Windows.h`) are essentially for Windows XP and older. I am unable to call functions such as [`GetTickCount64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because they require Windows Vista or higher. I have Windows 7, but these functions are still absent. I understand that linking to such functions would increase the requirements on my program, and I am OK with that.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Can I use the newer Win32 API with mingw? How?

Comment: It is an open source project, I'd assume they are waiting for your contributions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always [download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717422.aspx) the very latest platform SDK and have all you need. Use the header and lib files from the SDK.

Having said that, it may be that all you need to do is to define `_WIN32_WINNT` and/or `WINVER` to `0x0600` or higher to gain access to more recent APIs. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure what Windows header file mingw ships with.

Comment: I had no idea that Windows had an explicit downloadable SDK. This is great. Thanx!